# Get Request returning 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using the open weather API to make a get request based on a zipcode passed in as a query parameter. When I run the endpoint in Postman I receive a successful response and can see the data. When I run the request from my app (even with a hard coded value for testing) I get a 404 not found.

Endpoint from my server file:

```
const weatherCtlr = require('./controllers/weatherController);
app.get('/api/weather', weatherCtlr.getWeather);
```

My Controller

```
const axios = require('axios');
const {APIKEY} = process.env;

module.exports ={
     getWeather :(req, res)=>{
         const {zipcode} = req.body;
         axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipcode}&APPID=${APIKEY}`)
              .then(()=>{
                res.sendStatus(200);
              })
              .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
}
```

Client Side, (axios is imported)

```
getWeather =()=>{
      const {zipcode} = this.state.canyon;
     axios.get('/api/weather', {zipcode})
       .then(res=> this.setState({weather: res.data)})
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

I call the method on an on click

```
onClick={()=>this.getWeather()}
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is. I know the api key is good because I when I test my actual endpoint localhost.../api/weather and send a zipcode in the body it works.

Comment: So which axios call gets the 404, the server side one or the client side?

Comment: It’s the server side.

Comment: Have you simply compared the requests made via the browser's dev tools in the network tab to see what is different? What is different between the request Postman makes to the weather API and what your server requests? Is your app proxying requests to your server?

Answer (score 0):

What stands out is that you send a body to your server using `get`:

```
getWeather =()=>{
      const {zipcode} = this.state.canyon;
     axios.get('/api/weather', {zipcode})
       .then(res=> this.setState({weather: res.data)})
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
```

The GET method does not accept a body. Then on the server side you parse it out like this:

```
const {zipcode} = req.body;
```

I would be very surprised if you actually get that zipcode. Most likely that will be `undefined`.

So I would try changing your client side request to:

```
axios.post('/api/weather', {zipcode})
```

Once you get the response back from the API, you can send it back to your app like so:

```
       axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipcode}&APPID=${APIKEY}`)
              .then((response) => {
                res.json(response.data);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
                 res.json({msg: 'Error'})
              })
```

Comment: So I'm getting a response back of 200 which is good. But then how to access the data? I need to get that information to send it back to the client.